# How to readout unused serial pins (RTS, CTS, etc.)?

Tags: embedded, serial-port, serial-console

I have an interface for RS-232 communication. I need this interface for simple communication (no parity bit or flow control → TX, RX and ground) but now I have quite 4 pins unused (RTS, DTR, DCD/DSR, CTS) and wondered whether I could misuse these pins for some other signalling and for this I would need a way for reading out these pins. So how can I do that on my embedded Linux-based system?

`seterial` reports that the interface is in `16550A` UART mode and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART:
*"Handshake lines for control of an external modem, controllable by software."*

Anything else you need to know?

Comment: I believe, this forum post contains what you are looking for: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/manually-controlling-rts-cts-326590/#post1658463

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTS and DTR are output pins - which you can set.

DCD and CTS are input pins and can only be read.

The device is probably set for hardware handshaking by default. You can change this using [`tcsetattr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) (see CRTSCTS). Then you can use the `TIOCMBIS` ioctl to set RTS and DTR

Good references are:

- [Linux Serial HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.html)
- [Linux Serial Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/)

The above might be Linux centric.

To be more POSIX then see [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#5_1)

I have lifted this example from the guide:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int fd;
int status;

ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status);

status &= ~TIOCM_DTR;

ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, status);
```

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890903/how-to-properly-set-up-serial-communication-on-linux) you can find some opinions on how to set up the port properly.